# How to install Scala plugin for IntelliJ

Tags: scala, intellij-idea

I've installed IntelliJ IDEA and scala on my Windows machine, but those are not integrated and I'm not able to use scala in IntelliJ.
How can I configure and use both?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not directly related to a programming problem. It's more about how to follow the instructions to install a plugin for a particular IDE.

Comment: You are right. But I posted this question because I faced this situation and thought these simple instructions might help others.
Is there any other place to post this ?

Comment: Up-voting since this comes pretty high on google and it might be helpful (I fully understand @Mika'il argument though).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Open IntelliJ IDEA, go to File Menu --> Settings -->  [Or directly press Ctrl+Alt+S]
[image]

Click on "Plugins", and search "Scala". Select Scala plugin to install it.
[image]

If you have Proxy restrictions or any other problems, you may download the plugin to you machine from the below link and choose the option "Install plugin from disk"

https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/?id=1347

P.S. Sometimes the latest versions of plugin won't work. Try with a bit older version.

Comment: neither do Ctrl + Alt + S work nor that File Menu can be found .. try to attach an image to make it you answer to understand

Comment: Yeah, tried to use the latest plugin and had  compatibility issue.

Answer (score 10):

**Alternate Way**
Is open IntelliJ IDEA, click on Configure -> Click on Plugins -> Click on Install JetBrains Plugins -> Search for Scala -> Click on install button

Check the images

[Click on Plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vwfZa.jpg)

[Click on Install JetBrains Plugins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b6wyn.png)

Answer (score 5):

For IntelliJ Mac / IOS,

Click on `IntelliJ IDEA` text besides [image] on top left corner then `Preferences->Plugins-Install JetBrains Plugins-> Type Scala->Install`

Answer (score 4):

Click on File - > Settings and select plugins. Then select the Scala from the list provided and click Install. Once installed it will ask to restart the IDE

Answer (score 3):

For Mac, Click on IntelliJ IDEA -> Preferences -> Plugins.
Select scala and install. Restart the intellji for the changes to take effect.

Answer (score 1):

Right-click on project > Click Preferences > Expand Plugins

Find "Scala" and click install:

[image: intellij-right-click-open-preferences-intall-scala-plugin-screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

First time users in IntelliJ IDEA we checked whether Scala Plugin is available or not.

Go to File - > settings -> plugin -> Install -> Restart

Here is complete installations with step by step process with pictures:

http://commandstech.com/how-to-add-scala-plugin-on-intellij-idea-in-ubuntu/